# Proving that $a^x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

This is a question from a past exam paper for an analysis course, so we aren't allowed to use anything fancy and we need to prove things from first principles.

Here is the question.

> Let $a>1$, and define $f\colon\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$ by $f(x)=a^x$. You may assume the following facts:
>
> - $f$ is strictly increasing;
> - $a^{1/n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$;
> - $a^{-n}=(1/a)^n\to0$ as $n\to \infty$.
>
> 1. Show that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. Explain why this implies that $f$ is continuous everywhere.
> 2. Show that $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$. Explain why this implies that $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

I'm not sure how to go about these questions, my first thought was to try and involve the sequential criterion for continuity (i.e., that $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff for every sequence $(x_n)$, we have that $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$), but this is a universal statement (i.e., *for every* sequence), so I don't think it's really helpful since the given facts are about a specific sequence $(1/n)$ which converges to $0$. [And so $f(1/n)\to f(0)=1$, but for continuity we need it to be true for any sequence.]

I'm pretty much stumped, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: To prove continuity at $x=0,$ use not only $\lim a^{1/n}=1$ but also monotonicity of $f$ (the sequential criterion does'nt help). Continuity everywhere is then easy to deduce. To prove $\lim_{-\infty}f=0,$ use not only $\lim a^{-n}=0$ but, again, monotonicity of $f.$ The end is then easy.

Comment: How does the monotonicity help? I suspect...the squeeze theorem somehow?

Comment: Epsilon-delta proof, with (for the continuity at $x=0$) $\delta=1/n$ for some $n$ (depending on epsilon).